# how to solve prometheus no found token error

Tags: linux, prometheus

I would like to advise an application in another ip:

This is the web page:

[image: Prometheus target]

The error information is:

```
no token found
```

But when i visit http://111.231.136.80:8080/metrics

It seems it has got the data:

[image]

This is my promethus yml file:

[image]

The environment:

- Centos 7

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: and instead of posting pictures is it far better to copy/paste text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus requires data it scrapes to be in its text format, it cannot parse arbitrary other formats such as the JSON you appear to be getting here. You should use a client library such as https://github.com/prometheus/client_java to instrument your application and expose metrics in the right format.